# Make Zurb Foundation 5 top bar menu work without JavaScript (NESTED MOBILE)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Interested in what other people have done to make [Zurb Foundation 5 top bar](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html) working without JavaScript and in mobile viewpoint i.e `@media only screen and (max-width: 40em) { }`

On our [site](https://www.bybe.net/blog/) we are using .no-js and media queries, our css looks like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 40em) {

    /* Fix menu height */
    .no-js .top-bar {
        height:auto;
    }

    /* Add menu text */
    .no-js .toggle-topbar.menu-icon::after {
        color:white;
        content:"Menu";
        line-height:30px;
    }

    /* Remove menu link*/
    .no-js .top-bar .toggle-topbar.menu-icon a {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

This works pretty well, but I'm concerned about the design of the menu when we start introducing new menus and especially nested menus, obviously we could expand nested menus again, but on mobile you would be endlessly scrolling down.

So, this brings me to the question... How would you make the top bar work without JavaScript but still working with nested menus without expanding them until the parent is clicked, but bare in mind that the parents may be visit-able pages, this is the main issue.

Comment: I dont see any javascript here.. the `@media` tagg is just `CSS` .. no JS required .. `.no-js` is just a css class.  Javascript is not required at all to make a site responsive.

Comment: Sorry, removed the JavaScript tag. The question is how using .no-js can the current code be adapted to work with nested menus so when a user clicks a parent they see the child menus (but bare in mind that the parents are visitable links, too).

Comment: If there is no javascript, no validation will happen so it will still work the same! Thats the idea around `.no-js` :)

Comment: Maybe my question could clearer, I'm after a solution when disabling js. The question is not about .no-js, or javascript but rather making the menu behaviour similar to the orginal.